# Is there a trick to using small text?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, text

[image: png of ticket attached]I'm trying to create an email header with a ticket design on it. The ticket has small text on it which always seems to be pixellated, especially when I rotate it. no matter what I seem to set resolution to, (the 100% size is 600px) I can't write clear, but very small text. What am I doing wrong please?

Comment: What program are you using?

Comment: Welcome to **GD.SE** - glad to have you here. Please take a peek at [tour] to learn a little about our community; after that please also read [ask] and [answer] a question to understand how to frame a query here for best results and what to expect from answers and other replies. As initially written, your query is both broad and unclear, as you've precious little detail and no discussion of what you've tried and where that's failed. Could you refine this a bit after reading [ask] so we know how to help?

Comment: Hi - am trying it in Illustrator CC - and Photoshop too for good measure!

Comment: How about you attach this header so we can see what 'pixelated' means. Normally, AI and PS can handle small smooth text, so you're likely not ticking the right checkboxes.

Comment: hi - ok - I think I've done that... (sorry, new to this!)

Answer (score 4):

Design your email header @2x then scale it 50% in the html.

I assume you mean `600px` width is the target size for the image in the email, so make your photoshop document `1200px` width, then when you reference the image in html set "width=600" in the `img` tag.

This is common practice for making images appear sharper as rendered into HTML. It was called "designing for retina" when sharper, higher resolution displays started to become standard. https://designmodo.com/design-retina-displays/

You will often see the `@2x` in the filename, like this:

`imagename-800x600-@2x.png`

… which indicates it should be set at 1/2 size (400x300) in the HTML or CSS.

Comment: @tim accept my answer? … give it the green check. :)

Answer (score 1):

Photoshop is not good at rotating text so for a better result you can try rasterizing all text before rotating.

[image]

Comment: Yes, this makes sense - I've converted fonts to outline in Illustrator and I that's improved the rotation. thanks!